# JSON + Jquery formatting trouble

Tags: jquery, json

Here is my finished JSON:

```
{
    "message": [
        {
            "name": "John Doe (3)",
            "subject": "asdasd",
            "message": "lfkjas;dlfkja;sldfjals;dkfj;alsdkjf;laskdfj
al;sdkfj;alsdkfj


adslfkja;slkfja;sdlkfja;sdlkfj




as;dlkfja;lsdkjfa;lsdkfj",
            "date": "3/19/2012 2:20:51 PM",
            "senttotal": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is how it is stored in the database:

```
lfkjas;dlfkja;sldfjals;dkfj;alsdkjf;laskdfj al;sdkfj;alsdkfj  



adslfkja;slkfja;sdlkfja;sdlkfj     



as;dlkfja;lsdkjfa;lsdkfj
```

Here is how I insert the data from their message center into the database:

```
sql = ""
sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON"
sql = sql & " INSERT INTO message (DistID, subject, message, CreatedDate, StatusID)"
sql = sql & " VALUES (" & distID & ", '" & REPLACE(subject, "'", "''") & "', '" & REPLACE(message, "'", "''") & "', GetDate(), 1)"
sql = sql & " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewID"
```

As long as they write a message on one line it works just fine.  But when they start adding line breaks it seems to mess up the JSON.

The above JSON is the response copied using Firebug and formatted using JSONLint.

How can I fix this since a lot of people will be adding line breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace any line breaks with `\n`

Comment: is that as the data goes into the database, or as it comes out rightbefore i place it into the JSON.  Or both?

Comment: just before you add it to json...otherwise its not valid json. make sure it validates here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Alright, took me some trial and error, but I got this to work.  Thank you!